# After nightwatch useXpath use cannot setValue

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

My nightwatch came from vue-cli webpack template.
My problem is after usage of xpath nightwatch looses context and cannot find elements which exists.

example (works):

```
client.setValue('#NameInput', 'FirstName');
client.setValue('#MiddleNameInput', 'MiddleName');
client.setValue('#LastNameInput', 'LastName');
client.setValue('#AnswerInput', 'ChallengeAnswer');
client.useXpath().click("//option[contains(text(), 'Driver License')]");
```

example (does not work):

```
client.setValue('#NameInput', 'FirstName');
client.setValue('#MiddleNameInput', 'MiddleName');
client.setValue('#LastNameInput', 'LastName');
client.useXpath().click("//option[contains(text(), 'Driver License')]");
client.setValue('#AnswerInput', 'ChallengeAnswer');
```

Cannot find #AnswerInput element.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nightwatch is looking for `#AnswerInput` as if it was an xpath selector. After you `.useXpath()`, you have to switch back to using CSS with `.useCss()`.

```
client.setValue('#NameInput', 'FirstName');
client.setValue('#MiddleNameInput', 'MiddleName');
client.setValue('#LastNameInput', 'LastName');
client.useXpath().click("//option[contains(text(), 'Driver License')]");
client.useCss().setValue('#AnswerInput', 'ChallengeAnswer');
```

Comment: Yes I did not figure it out that it does not change do default or default does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the locate strategy for the selectors back to **css selector** using the `.useCss()` command.  Nightwatch defaults to the css selector.

```
client.setValue('#NameInput', 'FirstName');
client.setValue('#MiddleNameInput', 'MiddleName');
client.setValue('#LastNameInput', 'LastName');
client.useXpath().click("//option[contains(text(), 'Driver License')]").useCss();
client.setValue('#AnswerInput', 'ChallengeAnswer');
```

To help with any confusion about which locate strategy is being used, I usually put these commands on a line by themselves.

```
client
    .setValue('#NameInput', 'FirstName')
    .setValue('#MiddleNameInput', 'MiddleName')
    .setValue('#LastNameInput', 'LastName')
    .useXpath()
    .click("//option[contains(text(), 'Driver License')]")
    .useCss()
    .setValue('#AnswerInput', 'ChallengeAnswer')
```